# Jquery mouseenter mouseleave

Tags: jquery

i am begginer to jquery and have a simple problem..
I want to make list of posts from database..When i hover on heading its show hidden text..
Same like example on freelancers.com

This is my code..

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("tr").mouseover(function(){
            $(".neparan").show(); 
        }); 
        $(".neparan").mouseleave(function(){ 
            $(".neparan").hide(); 
        }); 
    }); 
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <?php 
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $lozinka = "";
    $baza = "jquery";
    mysql_connect($host, $user, $lozinka);
    mysql_select_db($baza);
    $upit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tekst");
    while ($red = mysql_fetch_array($upit)) { ?>
        <tr class="naslov">
            <td>
                <?php echo $red["naslov"]; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="neparan">
            <td>
                        <?php echo $red["tekst"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                            <?php echo $red["naslov"]; ?>
        </tr>
                            <?php echo "</br>";

                   } ?>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And css file..

```
.neparan {display:none;}

.naslov {color:red;}
```

Problem is that when I hover on tr all td is showing ...

Comment: You need to format that HTML.  It's unreadable all on one line.

Comment: Your DOM is malformed to start with, at the end of your table you open a table cell, which instead of closing you then double close a table row. Youve also tried to insert a <br/> tag between a td and a tr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of find() method will very likely help you get a better understanding of context with regard to searching for elements

http://api.jquery.com/find/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr").mouseover(function() {

        /* "this" refers to row being hovered*/                    
        $(this).find(".neparan").show(); 
    });
    $(".neparan").mouseleave(function() { 
        $(this).find(".neparan").hide(); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Same situations like previous code. Does not show or hide anything.

Comment: are you adding rows after page load? if so will need to use on() method to attach events....make a demo in jsfiddle.net that shows what problem is

Comment: I use jsfiddle.net This is my code ..http://jsfiddle.net/y4Y9b/ Still does not working..same situations like on my local machine. I am now format my php code and insert just html..Same effect like on my comp with php code..  Anybody?

Comment: what does that mean?  where's  link if you made one?

Comment: OK.. now that can see html working I understand... is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/y4Y9b/2/

Answer (score 0):

when the mouse over one `t`r you're showing all the `neparan` class with: `$(".neparan").show();`

Change the code:

```
$("tr").mouseover(function(){ $(".neparan").show(); }); // 
$(".neparan").mouseleave(function(){ $(".neparan").hide(); });
```

To:

```
$("tr").mouseover(function(){ $(".neparan", this).show(); });
$(".neparan").mouseleave(function(){ $(this).hide(); });
```

I used the context parameter:

> jQuery( selector [, context] )
>    selector A string containing a selector
>   expression
>   context- A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

Comment: Thanx to all but last code does not work.. When I put it to my document when I hover on tr it does not show anything.. When i try to find erorr in firebug console in firefox it does not show anything..No erorors in firebug.

Comment: @user1252682. I think you need to fix your HTML... Look at it!